# Why does Minori have a flower on her head?

Tags: toradora

In *Toradora SOS - Hurray For Foodies* (as listed on the DVD Cover of the NISA English Dub Release), I understand why Taiga and Ami have animal ears (Taiga is supposed to be the [Plam Top Tiger](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cd/Toradora%21_light_novel_volume_1_cover.jpg) and Ami is a dog because Taiga calls her Chihuahua). However, why does Minori has a flower on her head?

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnriKQI-fDs&feature=youtu.be&t=1m10s) (subbed)

NOTE: Toradora SOS 1 and 2 are on the first BluRay disc which had Episode 1 - 9 and I don't recall any character trait of Minori which would indicate the reason for the flower in those episodes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tenuous, but the kanji in Minori's name seem to have kind of a plant theme to them. In Japanese, her name is written 櫛枝 実乃梨 (*Kushieda Minori*). The kanji 枝, read *eda*, has the meanings "bough", "branch", "twig". The kanji 梨, read as *ri*, means "pear tree". That could be why they chose to symbolize her with a flower.

[Denshi Jisho page](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%AB%9B%E6%9E%9D%20%E5%AE%9F%E4%B9%83%E6%A2%A8) on the kanji in Minori's name.