# Why is Kaguya depicted with a flower growing out of her head when in her moron/fool form?

Tags: tropes, japan, kaguya-sama-love-is-war

In season 2 episode 2 of *Kaguya-sama wa Kokurasetai* ("Kaguya-sama: Love is War"), in the second skit titled *Kaguya-sama wa Okuritai* ("Kaguya Wants to Give a Gift"), Shinomiya Kaguya has a huge birthday cake prepared for the student council president Shirogane Miyuki. Overwhelmed by her feelings for the president in anticipation of celebrating his birthday together, Kaguya's usual personas gave way to her "moron form", in which she is not at all calculative and is very open to her feelings for the president.

In this form, Kaguya also has a pink flower growing out of the top right side of her head:

> [image: Kaguya in her moron form with a flower growing out of her head - 1]
> [image: Kaguya in her moron form with a flower growing out of her head - 2]

Is there any significance to the flower growing out of Kaguya's head in this visual representation of her mental state? Are there any other instances of anime/manga characters having flowers growing out of their heads to indicate a simple/idiot state of mind?

Comment: Not really flowers, but [mushrooms](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7530/2516)

Comment: @AkiTanaka So, mushrooms grow in a dark, gloomy places, therefore mushrooms growing on a person's head symbolize that they are mentally in a dark and depressed place. Analogously, flowers grow in sunshine and bright places, so flowers growing on a person's head symbolizes that they are mentally in a bright and happy place?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14845/why-does-minori-have-a-flower-on-her-head

Comment: @AkiTanaka Huh? It looks like post you link to says a mushrooms are for depressed/sad while flowers are for stupid/dumb/dense. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

There is a Japanese term [脳内お花畑 (*nōnai o-hanabatake*)](https://www.japandict.com/%E8%84%B3%E5%86%85%E3%81%8A%E8%8A%B1%E7%95%91) which translates literally to "garden in the brain". It's meant to indicate someone who is "off in their own world" or spacing out, so not thinking straight or not thinking at all.

Answer (score 5):

As you've already implied yourself, the flower on her head is most likely used as a visual comedic cue to indicate Kaguya's "simple" state of mind in that moment.

When it comes flowers growing on the head, it can have many different meanings. It can be a representation of the situation they're in, it can be a representation of the feelings they are going through, or it can simply be a visual cue as we see with Kaguya (or perhaps a combination).

It is also worthwhile to mention that in the Japanese culture, flowers are used heavily for symbolism. [The language of flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_flowers) in Japan is known as [Hanakotoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanakotoba). Different flowers can have different meanings depending on the context, and sometimes flowers used in manga or anime are specifically used to symbolize something. A very well-known example in the manga literature is the use of [roses (Bara)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bara_(genre)) to depict same-sex love between men and [lily flowers (Yuri)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_(genre)) to depict same-sex love between women.

A flower growing on a character can indicate some kind of flower symbolism that is related to the specific character, or it can more specifically indicate their feelings and emotions that they are experiencing. Whether the flower type itself has any meaning is up to interpretation.

[image][image: Asagao to Kase-san.]

Answer (score 2):

To supplement RobR's answer in the pilot/premiere, Kaguya wonders if Chika (Fujiwara) has flowers instead of a brain.

[image]

So even in this anime/manga, it's not just Kaguya. But of course here it's the same thing: Chika is arguably not thinking straight because Kaguya is extremely unlikely to go out on this date. [脳内お花畑 (nōnai o-hanabatake) aka "garden in the brain".](https://www.japandict.com/%E8%84%B3%E5%86%85%E3%81%8A%E8%8A%B1%E7%95%91)